# wpf textblock, maximum height - prefered width

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

For textblocks in wpf one can (easily) set the minimal, maximal and actual width/height.

Now in my case I have a textblock with potentially quite a bit of information. Which can be wrapped around. I wish that information to be contained on a specified "line" - maximum height. However the textblock should also adhere to a "prefered" width - the width CAN grow however if need be.

Thus: first word wrap and grow height while keeping width. Then once height is a certain value, stop growing that and start widening.

What I have so far is (importing relevant libraries for `TextBlock` and `TextWrapping`):

```
var tb = new TextBlock
tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
tb.Width = 96;
tb.MaxHeight = 96;
```

Obviously this just "fixes" the `Width`, where the height just grows to a maximum afterwich the text just overflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for a begavior like this:

```
public class TextBlockBehavior : Behavior<TextBlock>
{ 
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SizeChanged += AssociatedObject_SizeChanged; 
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SizeChanged -= AssociatedObject_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock temp = new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = AssociatedObject.Text,
            LineStackingStrategy = AssociatedObject.LineStackingStrategy,
            LineHeight = AssociatedObject.LineHeight,
            TextTrimming = TextTrimming.None,
            TextWrapping = AssociatedObject.TextWrapping,
            Height = AssociatedObject.Height
        };
        double maxwidth = AssociatedObject.MaxWidth - 10;
        double desiredHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
        while (desiredHeight > AssociatedObject.MaxHeight)
        { 
            temp.Measure(new Size(maxwidth, double.PositiveInfinity));
            maxwidth += 10;
            desiredHeight = temp.DesiredSize.Height;
        }

        AssociatedObject.MaxWidth = maxwidth;

    }
}
```

Note that a temporary TextBlock is measured, based on the current maximum width. Using its desired size, we can decide whether to increase the maximum width or do nothing.

You should set `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth` properties. Test:

```
<TextBlock MaxHeight="50" MaxWidth="100" Background="Red" TextTrimming="None" TextWrapping="Wrap"  MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:TextBlockBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

and code:

```
    private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBlock)sender).Text += "AAAA ";
    }
```

You might need to change somethings in cloning the textblock or changing the logic or changing the step size (I choose 10 pts here).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood you correctly.

***Markup***

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Tb" 
               MinWidth="120" MaxWidth="120"   MinHeight="23" MaxHeight="100"  
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               SizeChanged="TextBlock_SizeChanged_1"
               Background="#FFEAC9C9"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

</Grid>
```

***Code***

```
    private void TextBlock_SizeChanged_1(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;
        if (tb.ActualHeight >= tb.MaxHeight)
            tb.MaxWidth += 300;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Tb.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```